# How to better design async workflow triggered from kafka consumed messages?

Tags: asynchronous, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In my understanding we can consume kafka message and trigger async workflow based on message info. Here's one example:

```
private consumer() {
    request_info = kafka.getNextMessage()
    trigger_async_workflow(request_info)
}
```

and we'll keep consuming and triggering downstream workflow one at a time:

```
while () {
   consumer()
}
```

But concern is here we never know how long it'll take for `trigger_async_workflow()` to finish, so if takes quite a while due to whatever dependency outage, each consumer will be slow, then we'll suffer from kafka consumer lagging.

Also if `trigger_async_workflow()` fail, one approach is to produce the message to another delayed topic and then push back for retries.

So basically how to minimize the potential consumer lagging brought by async workflow unpredictability? Any other better design or tips? Thanks

Comment: Do you have indirect recursion here with functions "consumer" and "trigger_async_workflow"?  When a function is mutually called by another function in a circular manner, the function is called an indirect recursion function.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of concurrency my friend.  One of the most challenging topics in programming.  In the database world, there are isolation levels (usually 4) and explicit locking.  In the JavaScript world, there are a few options for handling asynchronous code:

1. callbacks, which allow you to provide functions to call once the asynchronous method has finished running
2. promises, which allow you to chain methods together;
3. async/await keywords, which are just some syntactic sugar over promises.

You should look into a callback.  Essentially you need to identify the dependent event/function and the dependency event/function.  Another way to think of these is the child function and parent function.  Yet another way is to think of these as the downstream function and upstream function.  Then you simply place a callback when one finishes.  This is the JavaScript way of locking a function until it's safe to run.

Is this good for performance?  Often times not.  Then get creative.  In the database world, they speak about anomalies which are prevented when using a specific isolation level.  Read about the categories of anomalies and which isolation levels avoid which anomalies.  In JavaScript, you will run into the EXACT same anomalies!  Think of a JavaScript function as a SQL event (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) So it's a good framework to think about what you might run into.

> A JavaScript callback is a function which is to be executed after
> another function has finished execution. A more formal definition
> would be - Any function that is passed as an argument to another
> function so that it can be executed in that other function is called
> as a callback function.

This explains the three methods very well with visuals.

https://medium.com/@anny.huynh32/callbacks-vs-promises-vs-async-await-a66668d44c7b

Comment: Question asked nothing about Javascript? Or databases?

Answer (score 0):

The better design, if at all possible, is to have your downstream application consume from Kafka directly rather than making any external network requests (and not waiting for a response) "at" it.

Otherwise, you need to await/block on your requests, which, yes, will cause lag in terms of time, but it's the only way to guarantee you track message success / failures and aren't doing "fire and forget" or "at most once" record delivery